# To what extent is the Singular Value Decomposition unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, svd, singular-values

In Adam Koranyi's article "[Around the finite dimensioal spectral theorem](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2695525)",
in Theorem 1 he says that there exist unique orthogonal decompositions.

What is meant here by unique?

We know that the Polar Decomposition and the SVD are equivalent, but the polar decomposition is not unique unless the operator is invertible, therefore the SVD is not unique.

What is the difference between these uniquenesses?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For distinct singular values, SVD is unique up to permutations of columns of the $U,V$ matrices. Usually one asks for the singular values to appear in decreasing order on the main diagonal so that uniqueness is up to permutations of singular vectors with the same singular values.

When singular values are repeated, you have additional freedom of rotating their subspace by an orthogonal matrix $O$, e.g. $U[:,i:j]O$ and $V[:,i:j]O$ for the subset of columns $i:j$ which correspond to the same singular value.

Comment: Can someone please explain more abstractly?

Comment: This is not quite right: if you have repeated singular values you can make arbitrary unitary base changes - not just permutations - on the corresponding singular vector spaces.

Comment: @Max: You're right, I've added that clarification.

Comment: As Ryan Howe's answer points out, this accepted answer is still not correct as currently written (as of 01/2024) even in the case of distinct singular values. For example, let $A=U\Sigma V^*$ and let $U'=e^{i\theta}U$ and $V'=e^{i\theta}V$ where $\theta$ is not an integer multiple of $2\pi$. Then $U'$ and $V'$ are unitary and $A=U \Sigma V^*=U'\Sigma V'^*$ with $U\ne U'$ and $V\ne V'$. This is just a simple example. Of course the applied magnitude-one scaling does not need to be uniform across columns.

Answer (score 2):

The singular values are unique however the columns of $U$ and $V$ are only unique up to the complex sign (because of how Gram-Schmidt works you're only guaranteed that).

Comment: what do you mean by $\textbf{complex}$ sign?

Comment: @georg See theorem 4.1 https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs322/2008sp/stuff/TrefethenBau_Lec4_SVD.pdf (complex scalar factors of absolute value 1)

Comment: thanks. Is this also true for eigenvalue problem, where the matrix A has complex entries, or is it just $\pm$?

Comment: Yes, the matrices U and V are the eigenvectors of the matrices $AA^{*}$ and $A^{*}A$. It still follows. It's because of how Gram-Schmidt works.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to *two reasons* mentioned by **Alex R**. above (columns of $U$, $V$ may be permuted following permutations of distinct singular values $\sigma_i$ on diagonal of $\Sigma$, and permutations caused by equal singular values) there is a *third reason* connected with the orthogonal complement, too.

Namely, suppose $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix (assume $m \ge n$). Then the singular value decomposition $A = U \Sigma V^T$ is found from the orthogonal decomposition $A=Q D Q^T$ of the positive semi-definite matrix $S=A^T A$ as by the following steps:

1. We take $V=Q$.
2. Set $\Sigma$ by adding to $\sqrt D$ some $m - n$ extra *zero* rows.
3. If the first $r$ singular values of $\Sigma$ are non-zero, then we define the first $r$ columns $u_1 \ldots, u_r$ of $U$ to be equal to the first $r$ columns of $AV$ divided by the values $\sigma_1 , \ldots, \sigma_r$ respectively.
4. Then the remaining $m - r$ columns of $U$ can be chosen to be **arbitrary** $m - r$ orthonormal vectors from the orthogonal complement $span^\perp(u_1 \ldots, u_r)$ of the subspace spanned by $u_1 \ldots, u_r$.

So we have **plenty of options to choose those** $m - r$ columns of $U$ (infinitely many in most cases).