Different value in V component in SVD
I have this matrix A that I want to factorize using SVD.
$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & -1 \\
2 & 1 & -4 
\end{bmatrix}  $
And I got the V matrix:
$ \begin{bmatrix}
-0.4513 & 0.07692 & 0.8890 \\
-0.3462 & 0.9031 & -0.2540 \\
0.82240 & 0.4224 & 0.3810 
\end{bmatrix}  $
But, when I crosscheck using wolfram alpha, the "number" is the same, but column 1 and 2 have the opposite sign. So, the matrix looks like this :
$ \begin{bmatrix}
0.4513 & -0.07692 & 0.8890 \\
0.3462 & -0.9031 & -0.2540 \\
-0.8224 & -0.4224 & 0.3810 
\end{bmatrix}  $
I already check my eigenvalue, eigenvector, the normalization, and nothing seems wrong.
The U and sigma component are the same. Only the V component that is different.
Is there more than one possibilities of V matrix? or something probably wrong with my calculation

See this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/426545/171839

SVD is not unique.If column k of V changes sign that would require a corresponding change  in  column k of $U$
